# Why are "curioso" and "único" masculine and singular in this exerpt?

Tags: gramática, género, número-gramatical

From "El último adiós desde Granada":

> Pues no lo sé. En realidad, esas famosas estatuas, en mi opinión, tienen poco valor artístico. Puede usted ver lo toscas que son, en comparación con la arquitectura de la Alhambra. Son algo **curioso**, y casi **único** en el mundo. Creo que ningún comerciante de arte se atrevería a comprar eso.

I didn't see anything even further back that these adjectives could modify besides estatuas. Is this an error, acceptable because of the main verb ser, or another grammar rule like "Ellos la quitan la chaqueta" where the singular comes from the fact that each person takes of one coat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they modify is "algo":

> **[algo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1nUry2t)**
>
> Del lat. *alĭquod*.
>
> 1. pron. indef. n. Designa una realidad indeterminada cuya identidad no se conoce o no se especifica. *¿Hay algo para mí? Ha hecho algo que no le perdono.*

"Algo" is a neuter indefinite pronoun (meaning "something"), so anything that modifies it must be in the same neuter gender (that happens to be the same as the masculine).

So, in the sentences you have:

> Son algo curioso
>   Son algo único en el mundo

In this case, you do know what "indetermined reality" the pronoun is referring to. You use "algo" just because you do not want to use the same word "estatua" over and over the text. So, to add more variety, you say "son algo único" instead of "son estatuas únicas" because you just used "estatuas" in a former sentence. Or it may be that by using "algo" the writer is trying to point out that they are something unique not only in the statues' world, but in a more general sense (being something famous despite having little value).

Comment: aha! I was automatically reading ALGO="[somewhat] strange" because of the parallel CASI.

Comment: @user135711 OK, now I understand your point. In fact, "algo" means also "un poco, no del todo", as in "está algo sucio". In that case, it would have been "son algo curiosas", indeed.

Comment: weird word to begin with. This adjective doesn't change endings I guess because of a collision with marine algae.

Comment: @user135711 you could ask that as another question. :D

Comment: @user135711 In fact, *algo* is never and adjective. It can be a pronoun (in the question example) or an adverb (in Carlos's comment). And adverbs have no gender.

Comment: @Gorpik how about "cada" then? There are words that are just weird. What's your explanation for that?

Comment: @user135711 What do you mean? *Cada* is an indefinite adjective, I does not vary with gender and has no plural. But there are many other adjectives that don't very with gender. I'm not saying that adjectives must vary with gender; I say that adverbs never vary with gender.

Comment: @Gorpik your explanation was correct and informative. I was just wondering if there was an interesting reason behind cada being invariable like it came from a foreign language like arabic maybe.

Comment: @user135711 Sorry, I misunderstood you. Anyway, in Spanish there are invariable adjectives coming from Arabic, indeed (e.g. *azul*); but there are also others coming from Latin (e.g. *verde*). Word origin does not usually explain that.